# SpreadsheetApp - how can I implement?

Tags: java, android, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to use command like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Expenses");
```

but I have a problem:
**SpreadsheetApp cannot be resolved**

I import jar:

```
- gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar
- gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar
```

and haeader of my file looks like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import com.google.api.services.plus.Plus;
import com.google.api.services.plus.PlusScopes;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
```

what I should add?

Comment: `import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetApp` ?

Comment: oh, you imported spreadsheet.* at the top. fyi, you would have imported SpreadsheetService twice

Comment: I try add this, but i have error: The import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetApp cannot be resolved

Comment: open the jar file. Is there SpreadsheetApp.class in that filepath?

Comment: no, there is no SpreadsheetApp.class in jar file

Comment: could You write me, where I can find correct jar file? with SpreadsheetApp.class?

Comment: How do you know that class is supposed to exist? from some documentation? do you have links to the documentation?

Comment: this is link to documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Answer (score 0):

Your example line of code is not java, it's Google Apps Script. Google Apps Script is a javascript-like language with dedicated APIs to access Google Services. [See the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

If you want to access a google spreadsheet from java, you should instead be looking at the [Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).